# Error Handling on bash script

Tags: bash, error-handling

Infinite loop on bash script and I want to run forever but (I guess) something goes wrong script is killed. Is there any way like try-catch, just continue to running forever, unconditionaly.

```
#!/bin/bash


 iteration=0

 for (( ; ; ))
 do
    process_id=`ps -ef | grep java | grep TEST | awk '{print $2}' `
    kill_command='kill -3 '$process_id
    time=`date | awk '{print substr($4,0,5)}' `
    last_write=`ls -l /files/*.txt | awk '{print $8}' `

    if [ "$time" != "$last_write" ]
    then
            $kill_command
            sleep 1

            $kill_command
            sleep 1

            $kill_command
            sleep 1

            /test/show_queue.sh
    fi

    let "iteration+=1"

    if [ "$iteration" == "30" ] 
    then
            let "iteration=0"
            $kill_command
            echo '------------' >> memory_status.log
            date >> memory_status.log
            prstat -n 7 1 1 >>  memory_status.log
            echo '------------' >> memory_status.log
            /test/show_queue.sh
    fi

    sleep 60
   done
```

Comment: Try `help trap` from the bash prompt.

Comment: I just add this line, waiting for a while. Thanks `trap "echo do_nothing" SIGINT SIGTERM`

Comment: What have you called your script?  Is it possible that `ps -ef | grep java` matches your script as well?  Try using `pgrep java` or `ps -C java` instead of `ps -ef | grep java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do it is to use two scripts. One with the loop and one which does the killing task :

```
for (( ; ; ))
do
  DoKillingTask
  rc=$? # <- You get the return code of the script and decide what to do
done
```

If it continues to be killed, Mikel (in comment of your question) is right.